# move row of selected cell to another worksheet not working properly

Tags: vba, excel

I got a Excel-file, where I add some rows with a little form. So far, so good. Now I try, to move (Select, cut, paste on other worksheet and delete on previous) with a macro. It works fine for the first time, but when I try to do it a second time, it's not working anymore. It still cuts the data from the first worksheet, but it overwrites it on the second one.
That's my code:

```
Sub moveToDone()
'
' moveToDone Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+m
'
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("erledigt").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C8").Select
    Sheets("Planung").Select
    Dim unusedRow As Long
    unusedRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

As you can see, I get the row from the selected cell, then I cut it, switch to the second worksheet called "erledigt" and paste it there on the first empty row. Then I delete it on the first one.
But as I said. It works fine on the first time, but then it just overwrites the previous one.

Comment: edit: It pastes it, but it overwrites the previous one.

Comment: You're always pasting the 5th row aren't you?

Comment: Oh wow. Always searching for some deep mistakes, but then it's just something really silly ._.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was fixed by @A.S.H

But I think no need to delete the source row, `.Cut`  do that.
And you can avoid using `.Select` here:

```
 With Sheets("erledigt")
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut .Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
 End With
```